# Where are WSS/MOSS 2007 registry entries stored on 64bit?

Tags: 2007, registry

I wonder if someone can tell me where, on a totally fresh install of WSS/MOSS 2007 on a 64bit machine, are the registry keys placed?

Is it:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\12.0

or is it:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\12.0

(note the **Wow6432Node** bit in the second one.)

(I ask because my dev box recently got corrupted, and the problem seems to be that while SharePoint is looking for the WSS registry key under Wow6432Node, it only exists in the other registry location.  I do not know what got corrupted -- whether it was the registry itself, or where SharePoint *looks* in the registry...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researching this myself, based on the info [here](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/internals-and-architecture/what-s-the-wow6432node-under-the-hkey_local_machine-software-registry-subkey-.aspx):

> The OS uses this key to present a
>   separate view of
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE for 32-bit
>   applications that run on a 64-bit
>   version of Windows. When a 32-bit
>   application queries a value under the
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\\
>   subkey, the application reads from the
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\\
>   subkey.

it would suggest that if you install 32-bit SharePoint on a 64-bit machine, the registry values will go under Wow6432Node.

I presume then if you install 64-bit SharePoint on a 64-bit machine, the values will go in the other location.

(...though this is confusing in my case, as I am running 64-bit SharePoint.. but something is obviously corrupted somewhere.)